# Checking the content of an array with comparison operators, concerning a specified order

Tags: javascript

I need a function which checks an array with integers. The integers have to be either in ascending order or in descending order. That depends from case to case.

I have figured out the following solution:

```js
const areVersionNumbersInExpectedOrder = (aNums, sExpectedOrder = "ascending") => {
            let passed = false;

            if (sExpectedOrder === "ascending") {
                if (aNums[0] < aNums[1] && aNums[1] < aNums[2]) {
                    passed = true;
                }
            } else if (sExpectedOrder === "descending") {
                if (aNums[0] > aNums[1] && aNums[1] > aNums[2]) {
                    passed = true;
                }
            }

            return passed
        };

        const versionNumbersAscending = [1, 2, 3];
        console.log(
            `Result ascending order: ${areVersionNumbersInExpectedOrder(versionNumbersAscending, "ascending")}`);

        const versionNumbersDescending = [3, 2, 1];
        console.log(
            `Result descending order: ${areVersionNumbersInExpectedOrder(versionNumbersDescending, "descending")}`);
```

Basically it works for me, but it is ugly. Especially the nested ifs.

**Is there are better way to solve the task?**

Comment: You're current solution depends on you knowing the array `length` before it is passed to your function. What happens when the array is longer / shorter than 3 elements? Your code would break or not return a true comparison. You should look at using a `for loop` to iterate each element in the array, comparing to the previous or next based on whether it is `descending` or `ascending` order. Also, if two elements are equal, they could still pass the test for ordering, so 1, 2, 2, 3, etc. having 2 < 2 would fail, even though the ordering is correct.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks for your hint. But in the test-scenario, for which I need the function, it will be always 3 elements. Because it will be based on static test-data.

Comment: While this may currently be true, you may want to try and learn to write your code as dynamically as possible to account for things which could become problematic in the future. If you go with the `for loop` solution, you won't have to worry about changing it later if your array ever grows or shrinks.

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes, you are right with what you say there, about more dynamic. I really should iterate over my current implemention ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a shorter approach with `every` and a callback depending on the expected order.

```js
const areVersionNumbersInExpectedOrder = (aNums, sExpectedOrder = "ascending") => {
    const
        order = {
            ascending: (b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => !i || a < b,
            descending: (b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => !i || a > b
        };

    return aNums.every(order[sExpectedOrder]);
};

console.log(areVersionNumbersInExpectedOrder([1, 2, 3], "ascending"));
console.log(areVersionNumbersInExpectedOrder([3, 2, 1], "descending"));
```

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this:

```js
const isSortedAscending = (v, i, a) => i === 0 || v >= a[i - 1];
const isSortedDescending = (v, i, a) => i === 0 || v <= a[i - 1];

const versionNumbersAscending = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(`Result ascending order: %o`, versionNumbersAscending.every(isSortedAscending));

const versionNumbersDescending = [3, 2, 1];
console.log(`Result descending order: %o`, versionNumbersDescending.every(isSortedDescending));

const versionNumbersAscending2 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(`arbitrary length arrays: %o`, versionNumbersAscending2.every(isSortedAscending));

console.log(`should fail: %o`, [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5].every(isSortedAscending));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is better:

```
const isInOrder = (arr, isAscending = true) => {
    let result = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        result = isAscending ? arr[i] <= arr[i + 1] : arr[i] >= arr[i + 1];
        if (!result) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really like your solution. The idea is great. But sadly I have to hint: It would fail, if the order is incorrect somewhere in the middle of the array. And the consecutive elements are in correct order again. Please try it with this array : const nums = [1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6];

Comment: You are right thanks, we need to return in the bottom of for loop if result === false.